# How to make code execute automatically every minute in asp.net mvc5 my websites

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have this code I have done using the application console and I want to use it inside my website using asp.net mvc5 in order to store the data it brings from the RSS feeds and store it in a database

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity;
using CodeHollow.FeedReader;
using CodeHollow.FeedReader.Feeds;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Entity.Core;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

namespace RssFeedBackEnd
{


public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        RssFeedDB db = new RssFeedDB();

        var qry = (from c in db.Links select c);

        foreach (var li in qry)
        {
            try
            {

                var feed = FeedReader.Read(li.adressLink);

                var item = feed.Items;


                if (feed.Type.ToString() == "Rss_2_0")
                {


                    //New n = new New();
                    foreach (var items in item)
                    {
                        string v = items.Id;
                        int h = validate(v);

                        if (h == 0)
                        {
                            try
                            {

                                New n = new New();

                                n.TitleNews = items.Title;
                                n.LinkNews = items.Link;
                                n.TitlePage = feed.Title;
                                n.LinkPage = feed.Link;
                                n.Linkimg = items.SpecificItem.Element.Element("enclosure").Attribute("url").Value;
                                n.IDurl = items.Id;
                                n.Pubdate = DateTime.Now;
                                n.EntryTime = DateTime.Now;
                                n.Description = items.Description;
                                n.IdCatogrey = li.CategorayID;
                                //n.NameCatogrey = li.Category.NameCategory.ToString();
                                db.News.Add(n);

                            }
                            catch { }

                        }
                    }

                }

            }

            catch { } 
        }
        db.SaveChanges();


    }


      static int  validate(string n) {

        int a = 0;

        RssFeedDB db = new RssFeedDB();


        var qry = (from m in db.News select m);

        foreach (var nws in qry)
        {
            if (nws.IDurl == n) { a =1; break; }
        }

        return a;

    }         
 }}
```

I hope to help me how to put it inside the web application and do his work every minute .

The idea of ​​my project is to fetch data (news) from RSS feeds links and store them in the database to display on my website.

I hope I've shown you very well what I want to do.

Comment: A website cannot do that. You need either your console application that a scheduled task connat run every 5 minutes, or create a Windows service. Because you already have a working console application, I suggest that you set-up a scheduled task.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification, but I don't know how  i can to start do that. Can you tell me where i can start to doing what you told me?

Comment: @KhaledTahaAhmed see my answer below. And then after you've read it, you can type "create windows scheduled task" into Google and you'll get plenty of guidance on what to do next.

Comment: You can put your code in a page that nobody knows about (the url could be a guid) and have a schedule task (could be on your computer) call that page.

Comment: @the_lotus why overcomplicate it like that? If something is running on a schedule in order to trigger another app to do a job, it might as well just do the task directly, instead of pinging a separate app to do it. Especially as the OP already has a console app which does the task. No need to go to the trouble of turning it into a web app, because they'll just need to create another console app to trigger it...

Comment: @KhaledTahaAhmed it reminded me when I was using a hosting service that didn't allow services to be installed but gave me the option to call a webpage on a schedule.

Comment: @the_lotus What you mean is that it doesn't support hosting like this that I'm going to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A web application is fundamentally unsuited for this type of task. A website's job is to respond to requests from others (usually people, via browsers) as and when they occur. It does not run automatically at specific times.

To achieve your goal, on your server you need either a Windows Service with a timer in it (which then executes the necessary code every time the timer expires), or a Windows Scheduled Task which triggers a specific application at regular intervals.

Since you already have a Console application which does the job you need, then the simplest solution for you is probably to set up a Windows Scheduled Task which executes the console application regularly.

N.B. You can of course still have a separate website which can display the data that the console application has saved in the database.

---

P.S. There are extensions to ASP.NET such as Hangifire and Quartz.NET which can add scheduling capabilities to a web application, but they are probably overkill for what you want to do in this case.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you tell me how I can start doing this?

Comment: type "create windows scheduled task" into Google and you'll get plenty of guidance on what to do next. It only takes 2 minutes to set up a scheduled task, especially as you've already written the console application

Comment: Thank you very much I don't think I will be able to do it in two minutes but thanks again for your beautiful motivation